# Could not set modules automatically via return key and bind IBAction methods rom Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I create iOS application using Xcode 8.3.3, but suddenly one day, Interface Builder is broken...

1. IBDesignable does not render styles on Storyboard and not raise any warnings and errors
2. Press return key at Custom Class textfield in Identity inspector, does not set Module and check "Inherit From Target", set "None" automatically
3. Does not show existed class names in Custom Class in Identity inspector while inputting
4. Could not bind components such as UIButton to declared IBAction methods in Swift files using drag and drop pressing the Ctrl key

I tried...

- Remove caches related to Xcode
- Restart Xcode and macOS
- Install Xcode 9 beta4 and run it

Of course, I confirmed file differences but there is no problem. Also I create a new project, all work fine in it.

What should I do for this project?

---

Images

**case 2** (just pressed a return key)

[image]

**case 3** (inputting)

[image]

**case 4**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I removed this project files and pull this project source codes via Git from a remote repository again, it works.